# Can't change project public facing name after adding Google authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Bit of a strange issue: I've created a Google authentication option in my Firebase project, but after having created it I can apparently no longer change the public-facing name, or the support email.

This is the user interface I see after I click the "pen" icon to edit the Google authentication settings: There is no option to change the public-facing name or the support email (which there was when I was adding the auth for the very first time)

[image: Can't change project public facing name]

However, I can see from [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/zCIfBbm06QM?si=PyPvFJRvpNc4qmMJ&t=493) that I should be able to do so. From the video:

[image: From the video]

Deleting the Google authentication option and adding it anew doesn't change anything: I just get the same window as in the first screenshot I posted above.

What's going on?